# Converting HTML to wikitext using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++, mediawiki

I've been trying to use regular expressions in notepad++ to automate a lot of changes I need to make to a document, but I don't think I really understand the syntax.

I have several sections of text that are similar to:

```
<a class='endnote' href='#cite1'><sup>[1]</sup></a>
```

the numbers are the only variable, and I would like to change it to:

```
<ref name="cite1" />
```

and

```
    <div id='cite1'>
    <p class='cite'><sup>1</sup>a bunch of text</p>
    </div>
```

the numbers are the only variable, and I would like to change it to:

```
 <ref name="cite1">a bunch of text</ref>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to replace 2 different combination of characters. Can you provide the expected output for each ?

Comment: ok, ill edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First

The first string can be replaced using this which validates the anchor tag has a class called endnote and pulls the href value not including the `#`.

Regex: `<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=['"]endnote['"])(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=['"]\#(cite[^'"]*)['"])(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?> .*?<\/a>`

Replace with: `<ref name="$1" />`

[image]

## Second

This second string can be replaced using this regex

Regex: `<div\b(?=\s|>)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?>.*?<p\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=['"](cite)['"])(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?><sup>([^<]*)<\/sup>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<\/div>`

Replace with: `<ref name="$1$2">$3</ref>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) to convert HTML back to wikitext, not invent your own parser ([yet another one](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers)).